# How to get rid of error?

Tags: java, audio, audio-streaming, keylistener

I'm writing text editor that is supposed to actually SAY the current key that is pressed. I managed to do that, I even prepared files. And everything works just fine, but when the amount of symbols becomes more than 29, the compiler says:

```
javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException: unable to obtain a line
at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.connect(PulseAudioDataLine.java:279)
at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:102)
at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:289)
at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioClip.open(PulseAudioClip.java:402)
at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioClip.open(PulseAudioClip.java:453)
at TextEditor$AreaListener.keyPressed(Main.java:81)
at java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Component.java:6161)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2801)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:5980)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2105)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4564)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2163)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4390)
at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1881)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:749)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1025)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:892)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:713)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4434)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2163)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4390)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:649)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:96)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:608)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:606)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:105)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:116)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:622)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:620)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:105)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:619)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:275)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:200)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:190)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:185)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:177)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
```

Here is the part of my source code where is described a class that implements KeyListener interface. This class is a listener of my main text area.

```
class AreaListener implements KeyListener {
    @Override public void keyPressed( KeyEvent e) {
        try {
            AudioInputStream result1 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("/home/nikkka/Desktop/alphabet/blank.wav"));;
            if(new Character(e.getKeyChar()).isLetter(e.getKeyChar()))
                result1 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("/home/nikkka/Desktop/alphabet/"+e.getKeyChar()+"_EDITOR.wav"));
            DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, result1.getFormat());
            Clip clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            clip.open(result1);
            clip.start();
        } catch(Exception e1) {e1.printStackTrace();}}
    @Override public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
    @Override public void keyTyped(   KeyEvent e) {
    }
}
```

I can't see what's the problem?... Moreover, why something that works for first 29 symbols, shouldn't work on more? Maybe it's because I have to close the clip by `clip.close()` after `clip.start()`? Please, help :-S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this error because the [`Line`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Line.html) is not available due to resource restrictions, according to the documentations described [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html#getLine%28javax.sound.sampled.Line.Info%29).

I think you should close the [`Line`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Line.html) after you used it with the [`Line.close()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Line.html#close%28%29) method.

*EDIT*: 
The proper way of doing it could be the following:

1. create a `Clip` object when starting the application or creating objects for handling the input area
2. use that `Clip` object when the key is pressed in the input area
3. `stop()` and `close()` the `Clip` when the application is exiting or destroying the input area

This would save the resources.

Comment: well, thank you but i can't actually understand what do you mean... could you please be more concrete? :S what line do you mean? :S

Comment: You get a `Line` at the line says `Clip clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);`. After you used it you should free up the resource with the `close` method.

Comment: you mean i should write clip.close()?

Comment: Yes, because `Clip` is a subclass of `Line`.

Comment: I did it, and now the program is stuck :S I suppose it's because clip.start() runs in new thread and is still active when clip.close() is called. Is that right?

Comment: Can happen I have never used `Clip` and `Line`, that's why I said you should free it up _after_ you used it.

Comment: BTW why don't you get a `Line` on the start and play the sound with that object and free it up before you exit from your program.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a compiler error message.

It is a runtime error which I would assume means it could not read the data in the sound file.  Either the file is corrupt or has a format which is not supported.

Comment: Actually, the only key I use for testing, is the "a" key. And for 29 times it works just fine. It's the same "a" key and the same "a_EDITOR.wav" file that is used by program. And I still can't see the reason, why...